# Broadcast join in Spark 3.2.2 returns "NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourcePartitioning"

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We are migration one of our spark application from spark 3.0.3 to spark 3.2.2 with cassandra_connector 3.2.0 with Scala 2.12 version , and we are getting below exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: \
    Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: \
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourcePartitioning
```

```
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourcePartitioning, value: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourcePartitioning@606805ac)
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AQEShuffleReadExec, name: outputPartitioning, type: interface org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.Partitioning)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AQEShuffleReadExec, AQEShuffleRead local
+- ShuffleQueryStage 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(msisdn#29, record_creation_dttm#472, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=85]
      +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(msisdn#29) AND isnotnull(record_creation_dttm#472))
```

Default spark optimized it to use broadcast join and application  failed with serialization exception . But if I explicitly disable broadcast join application  is working .

**Note** : On further digging down I found out that spark3.2.2 AQE and cassandra tuning parameter [*"spark.cassandra.sql.inClauseToJoinConversionThreshold": "1"*] creating this conflict, For now I resolved the issue with adding config
*"spark.sql.adaptive.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold": "-1"*[Disabling AQE Broadcast join]

Sample code can be found here
[sample code](https://github.com/soumen721/spark-aqe-test/blob/main/TestAQECassandraJoin.scala)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to add more details to get help. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez any suggestion please